# About "der" in this sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

In the *Vorwort* to this book, the philosopher says the following:

> Dieses Buch *wird* vielleicht nur **der** *verstehen*, **der** die Gedanken, die darin ausgedrückt sind-oder doch ähnliche Gedanken-schon selbst einmal **gedacht hat**.

(Ludwig Wittgenstein, *Tractatus logico-philosophicus*, p.7)

If I break down this sentence, I get the following clauses:

> 1. Dieses Buch wird vielleicht nur **der** verstehen
> 2. **der** die Gedanken ... schon selbst einmal **gedacht hat**
> 3. die darin ausgedrückt sind-oder doch ähnliche Gedanken-

Is the *der* in the first clause a demonstrative pronoun similar to *this one* in English, and the *der* in the second clause the relative pronoun relating back to the one in the first clause, as I think they are?

Is the word order in the first clause, *Dieses Buch wird vielleicht nur der verstehen*, considered very formal?

After all, I think that this clause could have been written like this:

> Vielleicht **wird** *nur der* dieses Buch **verstehen**

Comment: You could replace the first "der" by "derjenige", so "this one" is correct.

Comment: @IQV As far as I know, _derjenige, diejenige, dasjenige, plural diejenigen_ are even more formal than _der, die, das, plural die_. Correct?

Comment: The demonstrative pronoun *derjenige* (and friends) is a combination of the demonstrative pronouns *der* and *jener*. It's not a matter of formality but perspective. *Der* focuses on pointing on someone/something, while *jener* focuses on the fact the one or thing in question is in the distance. So *derjenige* is a distinct person in the distance – the reader. He's both addressed and known to be far away from the author.

Comment: @Janka Could Wittgenstein have used _derjenige_ instead of _der_ in this sentence?

Comment: Yes, but it's not his style, I think.

Comment: @Janka I see. And maybe you can also tell me something about the secondary question about the word order in the first clause of this sentence. Danke!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your first question has been answered sufficiently in the comments, here an answer to your second question:

No, the sentence with its beginning

> Dieses Buch wird vielleicht nur der verstehen, der...

will not be considered "very formal". It is a completely "normal" (average, unmarked, unremarkable, unconspicuous) sentence.

Whereas your alternative

> Vielleicht wird nur der dieses Buch verstehen

sounds more casual and oral, and not really appropriate for the context.

Word order is a means for giving emphasis to things. First position in a sentence is emphasized. Wittgenstein chose to emphasize *dieses Buch*, not *vielleicht*.

Comment: I see. And my re-writing it is also grammatically correct?

Comment: *Vielleicht wird nur der dieses Buch verstehen, der...* is grammatically perfectly correct. It is just a little bit too casual for the context. However, had Wittgenstein written this instead of what he actually wrote, still nobody would have accused him of sloppyness.

Comment: Comments do no count as answers. There is nothing wrong with repeating what someone else wrote in a comment.